# past subjunctive after the verb "to want"

Tags: subjunctives

I read the following sentence:

> I wanted my daughter to make her bed.

If I wish to use the subjunctive mood instead of the (more usual) infinitive form, would it be "I wanted that my daughter made her bed" ?

Comment: How can it be subjunctive with past tense "made"? The subjunctive uses the plain form of the verb -- in this case "make", as in "I demanded that my daughter make her bed". In any case, the verb "want" does not license subjunctive clauses.

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive wrong then? It mentions "Try to imagine a tool that made that easy for citizens" as an example of past subjunctive

Comment: There's no subjunctive clause in that example. As I said, a subjunctive contains a plain form of the verb as in the example I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

"I wanted that my daughter made her bed" doesn't contain a subjunctive. The subjunctive of *make* is always *make*. ('I insisted he make some toast.')

If you were to look at some examples of the [subjunctive mood](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm) you might notice how often it takes 'that':

> You demand that I be available
>
> I ask that you be truthful
>
> it's essential that she be here.

But when it is used as a conjunction, **that** can't follow **I wanted**.

**I insisted that my daughter make her bed** uses the subjunctive correctly, but it doesn't precisely mean "I *wanted* my daughter to make her bed".

**I asked that her bed be made** also uses the subjunctive but it doesn't say who should make the bed!

**I wished my daughter's bed were made by her** is absurdly convoluted!

The original sentence is fine. The subjunctive mood is not suitable for all sentences.

Comment: The subjunctive is a mood, not a tense, therefore there is no such a thing as "subjunctive of make". I suppose you meant the "subjunctive present of make".  Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Comment: @Alan Evangelista Yes, you're right. It was a typo. I meant the "subjunctive form of make". I directed the questioner to https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm because it explains the subjunctive mood simply. "The subjunctive form of 'make'" is their phraseology. There is indeed no "subjunctive of 'make'".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista No: modern grammar considers the subjunctive to be a clause type that uses a plain form of the verb.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista No: English does not have an inflectional mood system. Your confusing English with Latin, which does have a subjunctive mood.  In English, the subjunctive is a clause type that uses a plain form of the verb. Forget the rubbish  you read on the 'Net.

Comment: @BillJ I see two distinct inflections in "You demand that I be available" and "I wish he were here". Anyway, I understand now that the subjunctive present is used for past, present and future and therefore its name is misleading.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista In your first example, "be" is not inflected for mood, but is simply the plain form of the verb. It is a subjunctive, but it's clause type, not a mood form. In your other example, "were" is 'irrealis' (or the ill-named past subjunctive) -- an isolated mood form and a relic from earlier stages of the language. Mood is generally marked by the modal auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @BillJ Now I understand why we disagreed before. IMHO it is just a matter of terminology. It seems to me (layman) that seeing the "subjunctive present" as a "clause type" or a "mood" is two ways of interpreting and modeling the same phenomenon. As I am not a linguist, I prefer the latter because a "subjunctive mood" is closer to the same phenomenon in Romance languages.

Comment: @BillJ Regarding the alternative name "irrealis" given to the "past subjunctive", IMHO it can also be misleading because it is used only for hypothetical situations in the present ("If I were rich"); such situations in the past use the past perfect ("If I had been rich, ...") and in the future use the present ("If I'm rich someday, ...")